# Unable to push changes into gerrithub.io

Tags: github, gerrit

I have the repo here [Link to the repo](https://review.gerrithub.io/#/admin/projects/ardyflora/virginPulseAuto)

I cloned it and did some changes but when I try to push it.

It gives me the following error:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Username for 'https://review.gerrithub.io': ardyflora
Password for 'https://ardyflora@review.gerrithub.io':
fatal: Authentication failed for 
'https://review.gerrithub.io/ardyflora/virginPulseAuto/'
```

I have even added the ssh key. Any pointer or help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication failure for HTTPS. Better you can take a try with SSH.

Copy the URL for SSH of your repository using a browser and update your local `origin`.

```
$ git remote set-url origin <ssh-clone-url>

$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Comment: Thanks, One change:
`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

Comment: Updated. Does `git push origin master` not work for you? Maybe for `gerrit`, not sure.

Comment: `git push origin master` updates the repo.  
but when I do `HEAD:refs/for/master` it sends it to the gerritreview page.